# Vuejs component consuming lot of memory

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, firefox, memory-leaks

I have a page in my application which is built in vuejs and does an api call every second using setTimeout in mount method.

When I do about:memory in Firefox (ver 78.11) on Linux it displays around 1 GB memory and energy impact as medium after I kept the tab open for about 5 hours.
It started from like 30MB and have reached after 5 hrs to 1.54 GB.

We are restricted to only use firefox and I cant figure out what's causing the issue.
This vue component is embedded in laravel blade.

I am calling the loadData function on mounted which then calls setTimeout and I am cleaning intervals too.

Though I believe beforeDestroy would never be triggered as the component is displayed forever and not conditionally.

```
<script>
    Vue.component('alertbody', {
        data: function () {
            return {
                alerts: [],
                loadInterval: null
            }
        },          
        template: `
                    <div class="box-body" style="min-height: 510px; overflow:hidden;">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                      <div v-for="(alert, index ) in alerts"  v-bind:key="alert.eventid" class="panel panel-default" style="word-break:break-all;">
                          <div class="panel-heading" v-bind:style="'background-color:'+alert.color" role="tab"  v-bind:id="'heading'+index">
                                <div class="ml-5">
                                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                                           v-bind:href="'#collapse'+index" aria-expanded="true">
                                               <h4 class="panel-title text-dark">
                                                  <div class="text-bold">@{{ alert.host }}</div>
                                                  <div class="text-sm">@{{ alert.description }}</div>
                                              </h4>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`,

          mounted: function () {
            this.loadData();
          },
        methods: {
            loadData: function () {
                $.get('{{ route('
                getAlertsPersistent
                ') }}', function (response) {
                    this.alerts = response['alerts'];
                }.bind(this)
            )
                ;

                if (this.loadInterval) {
                    clearInterval(this.loadInterval);
                }

                this.loadInterval = setTimeout(this.loadData, 1000);
            },
        },
        beforeDestroy: function () {
            this.alerts = [];
            delete this.alerts;
            clearInterval(this.loadInterval);
        }

    });
    new Vue({el: '#alertbody'});

</script>
```

As in the below picture CMS displays around 500MB memory.
[image: Firefox Memory Screenshot]

I am not sure if occupying that much memory as its making calls every second is ok.
FYI, After few mins 500MB reduced to 300 MB.

Can anyone suggest if there's any memory leaks?

TIA

Comment: sometimes the problem is libraries external to Vue, do you use an external library?

Comment: If you are using Vue3 it should be `beforeUnmount()` not `beforeDestroy` [https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram)

Comment: No, I am using vue2